# What does "A1114E: Expected register relative expression" mean?

Tags: assembly, arm, addressing-mode

Hi im trying to call a assembler subroutine from c and get this error. On the Arm websites, there is just stated that this error exists..
C Code

```
    #include <stdint.h>
extern void out_word(uint32_t out_address, uint32_t out_value);
extern uint32_t in_word(uint32_t in_address);
int main(void){
        uint32_t value = in_word(0x60000200);
        uint32_t address = 0x60000100;
        out_word(address,value);
    return (0);
}
```

Assembler Code

```
                PRESERVE8
                AREA myCode, CODE, READONLY
                EXPORT in_word
                EXPORT out_word

in_word         PUSH {R1-R7}
                LDR R1, R0 ; line which produces the problem
                LDR R0, [R1]
                POP {R1-R7}
                BX LR
                
                
out_word        STR R1, [R0]
                BX LR
                   
                END
```

Comment: `LD` is a *load from memory* instruction. To copy between registers you need to use the (perhaps badly named) *move* instruction `MOV`.

Comment: `R0` isn't a memory addressing mode.  Your `[R1]` on the next line is.  You know you could `ldr r0, [r0]` if you wanted, right?  IDK why you're pushing/popping so many registers either.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know either, I deleted it now and it still works. Thank you

Comment: If you want to post your working code, post an actual *answer*, not an edit to the question.  It's 100% fine to answer your own question, as long as it's written as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong instruction. LDR - Load with immediate offset, pre-indexed immediate offset, or post-indexed immediate offset

You need to use `mov` instruction

Answer (score 0):

Final solution which works

```
                PRESERVE8
                AREA myCode, CODE, READONLY
                EXPORT in_word
                EXPORT out_word

in_word         LDR R0, [R0]
                BX LR
                
                
out_word        STR R1, [R0]
                BX LR
                   
                END
```